# Confusion about definition of primitive polynomials

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am working through Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and am confused about his definition of primitive polynomials on page 129.

He defines $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_nx^n$ on $\mathcal{O}$ with maximal ideal $\frak{p}$ to be primitive if $f(x)\not\equiv 0 \pmod \frak{p}$, \textit{i.e.} if

$$|f|=\max\{|a_0|, \dots, |a_n|\}=1$$

I don't quite understand what the second definition means in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $|\cdot|$ refers to the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic absolute value on the field of fractions $K$ of $\mathcal{O}$. Recall that $\mathcal{O}=\{x\in K:|x|\leq 1\}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\{x\in K:|x|<1\}$.

Therefore $|a_i|\leq 1$ for all $i$ since the $a_i$ are in $\mathcal{O}$, so the condition $\max\{|a_0|,\dots,|a_n|\}=1$ is saying that at least one of the $a_i$ is not in $\mathfrak{p}$.